# Простейший цикл на PHP

Tags: php, циклы

Имеется простейший код

**HTML**:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="string">
    <input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
if (isset($_POST['ok']))
{
    $string = $_POST['string'];

    for ($i = strlen($string); $i < 0; $i--)
    {           
        echo $string;
    }
}
```

Как я представляю работу скрипта: В форму HTML вводится строка. Переменной **$i** присваивается длина строки. После чего, эта самая строка, которую мы вводили ранее, с помощью оператора **echo** выводится **$i** раз. Однако при вводе строки оператор echo не печатает ничего. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в значке `<` вместо нужного здесь `>`:

```
for ($i = strlen($string); $i > 0; $i--)
```

что в переводе на человеческий означает: "выполнять тело циклa пока выполняется условие `$i > 0`"

Comment: Глупая ошибка с моей стороны. Спасибо,  проблема решена

Comment: А разве isset($_POST['ok']) отработает корректно когда <input type="submit" name="ok"> ? Это же не поле формы и тогда условие не сработает и вывод опять будет пустой.

Comment: @SergeyN Браузеры включает в данные формы пару `name=value` нажатого `input` (или `button`) с `type="submit"`. Если `value` отсутствует, браузер назначит что-то свое, например, `"Submit"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit